# How to execute this code using dependency injection, spring and maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm new to Spring, Maven and Unit Testing (TDD), and I must use all 3 at the same time for a new project.
I've been reading tutorials and code examples for the past day and cannot find a solution.

For this example (a calculator), let's say I have the following Interface:

```
public interface CalculatorService {
  public double add(double input1,
                    double input2);

  public double substract(double input1,
                          double input2);
}
```

This is the implementation of the interface, dependency injection style:

```
public class MathApplication {
  private CalculatorService calcService;

  public void setCalcService(final CalculatorService calcService) {
    this.calcService = calcService;
  }

  public double add(final double input1,
                    final double input2) {
    return this.calcService.add(input1, input2);
  }

  public double substract(final double input1,
                          final double input2) {
    return this.calcService.substract(input1, input2);
  }
}
```

The tests class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MathApplicationTester {
    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

  @InjectMocks // Marks where to inject the mocks.
  MathApplication mathApplication = new MathApplication();

  @Mock // Marks the mocks to be injected.
  CalculatorService calcService;

  @Test
  public void whenAddCorrectThenDoOperation() { 
    // GIVEN

    // WHEN
    when(this.calcService.add(10.0, 20.0)).thenReturn(30.00); // Adds the behaviour of calc service
                                                              // to add two numbers.

    // THEN
    assertThat(this.mathApplication.add(10.0, 20.0)).isEqualTo(30.0); // Tests the functionality
                                                                      // added.
    verify(calcService, times(1)).add(10.0, 20.0);
  }

    @Test
    public void whenSubstractIsCorrectThenDoOperation() throws Exception {
        // GIVEN

        // WHEN
        when(calcService.substract(20.0, 8.0)).thenReturn(12.0);

        // THEN
        assertThat(mathApplication.substract(20.0, 8.0)).isEqualTo(12.0);
    }
}
```

And this is the Main, as I have it right now:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TddMockitoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TddMockitoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My question is: what do I have to put into the main, or how do I run this code, if let's say I want to make an addition or a subtraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly you want to run this application using spring. Let get Started.

Spring in order to make dependency injection it needs to read configuration for your dependency, Spring does this reading annotation on classes that you mark( Earlier by reading XML config)

The best way to start with spring is to use [Spring-Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Step 1. Add Spring dependency in your pom.xml

```html
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Step 2. Create Spring boot main class

```html
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When you add spring dependency in classpath and add @SpringBootApplication annotation on Java class spring system identify this as spring application. it scans relevant packages and prepares for dependency injection.

Step 3. Create Spring configuration

```html
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Component
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public CalculatorService getCalculatorService(){
        CalculatorService calcService = new CalculatorServiceImpl();
        return calcService;
    }
}
```

This tells Spring how to instantiate CalculatorService.

Step 4. Autowire dependecy

```html
public class MathApplication {
    
    private CalculatorService calcService;

    @Autowired
    public void setCalcService(final CalculatorService calcService) {
        this.calcService = calcService;
    }

    public double add(final double input1,
                      final double input2) {
        return this.calcService.add(input1, input2);
    }

    public double substract(final double input1,
                            final double input2) {
        return this.calcService.substract(input1, input2);
    }
}
```

Now you can run this application from your IDE or via Maven.

P.S 
When someone ask you to TDD it doesn't mean that you need to run the test from main class, it means that you should write the test first and then write the business logic, but you only run actual business logic from the main.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the main goal of your project is to make use of TDD and JUnit then you can just run your unit tests by right clicking the MathApplicationTester class in your IDE and running it with JUnit.

Comment: I'm already running the tests, the thing is to run the whole application and make it work. Right now the tests do work, but I can't achieve to make an operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the Unit test then you can right click on the class and run it with JUnit.
If you want to do addition or subtraction , then either you will have to create a web page where you can take the inputs  and then click on add/subtract button which will call your methods ,or you can expose the add/subtract method as web service and call them.